# Apply conditional opacity in plotly figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

#### Problem

I'm trying to create a Plotly chart where I would like to apply conditional opacity if an entry is selected (column 'selected': True or False) or not. Unfortunately, the things I tried did not work out. How can I apply conditional opacity to my Plotly chart?

### What I tried

I tried to hand the 'opacity'-values of the dataframe to the `opacity` argument of `px.scatter()` to, which resulted in a ValueError.

I also tried to update the traces with `product_fig.update_traces(marker=dict(opacity=df['opacity'].tolist()))`, which unfortunately also did not work and did not apply the opacity to the points in the scatter plot.

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

def build_product_data_fig(df: pd.DataFrame) -> go.Figure:

    df['opacity'] = df['selected'].apply(lambda x: 0.8 if x else 0.2)

    product_fig = px.scatter(df,
                             x='emission',
                             y='weight_gram',
                             color='category',
                             size='price',
                             template='plotly_dark')

    return product_fig
```

### Sample data

| emission | weight_gram | category | selected | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120.4 | 1250 | A | True | 32.0 |
| 92.0 | 950 | B | False | 20.0 |
| 105.5 | 1100 | A | True | 25.0 |
| 87.8 | 800 | B | False | 18.0 |
| 100.2 | 1050 | A | False | 22.0 |
| 110.6 | 1150 | A | True | 28.0 |
| 95.2 | 900 | B | False | 16.0 |
| 115.8 | 1200 | A | True | 30.0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

I got the solution I wanted by first creating an RGB color map for the categories. Then I added the opacity to the color map by creating the according RGBA values and adding the related opacity based on the `selected` column.

```
import colorsys
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def create_color_list(df: pd.DataFrame) -> List[str]:
    
    unique_categories = df['category'].unique()
    category_color_map = {}

    num_categories = len(unique_categories)
    color_map = []
    for i in range(num_categories):
        hue = i / num_categories
        rgb = tuple(round(i * 255) for i in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, 0.7, 0.9))
        color_map.append(rgb)

    for i, category in enumerate(unique_categories):
        category_color_map[category] = color_map[i % len(color_map)]

    color_list = []
    for category, selected in df[['category', 'selected']].values:
        if selected:
            opacity = 0.8
        else:
            opacity = 0.2
        color = category_color_map[category]
        rgba = f"rgba({color[0]}, {color[1]}, {color[2]}, {opacity})"
        color_list.append(rgba)
        
    return color_list


def build_product_data_fig(df: pd.DataFrame, color_list: List[str]) -> go.Figure:

    product_fig = go.Figure()
    product_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='markers',
                                     x=df['emission'],
                                     y=df['weight_gram'],
                                     marker=dict(
                                         color=color_list,
                                         size=df['price'] / 40)
                                     ))

    product_fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark')

    return product_fig

color_list = create_color_list(df)
product_fig = build_product_data_fig(df, color_list)
product_fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the plotly graph object and specify the color as RGBA and the transparency, you can draw the graph you intend.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#df['opacity'] = df['selected'].apply(lambda x: 0.8 if x else 0.2)

color_list = []
for x in df[['category','selected']].values:
    if x[1] == True:
        op = 0.8
    else:
        op = 0.2
    if x[0] == 'A':
        color_list.append('rgba({},0,{},{})'.format(0,255,op))
    else:
        color_list.append('rgba({},0,{},{})'.format(255,0,op))
        
product_fig = go.Figure()
product_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='markers',
                                 x=df['emission'],
                                 y=df['weight_gram'],
                                 marker=dict(
                                     color=color_list,
                                     size=df['price'],
                                 )
                                )
                     )
product_fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white')
product_fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what I want, is that the color for a ‘category’ should be the same and only the opacity of a category should be 0.2 if unselected or 0.8 if selected. Concretely, the variable ‘selected’ should only change the opacity of the color that comes from the category. With your approach it seems that I won’t include the logik of the ‘selected’ column. Would this mean I have to create the colors per category and then create two RGBA per category for the different opacities depending if a record is selected or unselected. Resulting a combined variable of ‘category’ and ‘selected’ for mapping?

Comment: I did not quite understand your intention. You need 4 RGBA as you perceive. So I created a function to determine by category and select and created a list of colors. Updated the code and graphics.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. Additionally, I had to deal with the number of categories in the actual df. I added my solution below.